# Image comparison Result image registration. Normalized cross correlation Opencv

Tags: image, opencv, comparison, registration, cross-correlation

I need to check how good the result of one image registration process' was. For it I thought of using Normalized Cross correlation between both images: base and result of the process. The problem is that I never worked with cross correlation and I dont know if it could be the better approach.

Then with the result I could see where the images are more dissimilar and try to improve the registration on this part of the image.

Would I need to make a two dimensional cross correlation? then I would obtain a map of dissimilarities,right?

Any help/suggestion would be useful

Comment: What are the two images you are trying to register? Could you show some example please.

Comment: At the end what I did was:
1st Convert the images to binary
2nd Absolute difference between correspondent pixels
3nd I took the square of this last result.
4th I made a erode operation.
In this way I obtained an image where the white parts are the dissimilar ones the rest remain black and it is where the program needs to be improved. Thanks

Comment: What simiilarity measure did you use initially to register the images? How are the image intensities related?  Is there a non-linear relationship between them?